# centralized growl forwarder

Tags: linux, notifications, forwarding, growl

Multiple services on servers I'm running can be configured to output growl notifications, I'd like a centralized forwarder to run on a Linux box

I'm looking for either an [implementation](https://github.com/kfdm/gntp-regrowl) or tips on writing an implementation of a server to listen on `<ip:port>` and accept GNTP protocol packets and forward/'re-growl' them to multiple clients.

Clients (notify-my-android, offsite linux/windows desktops) either would have to register that they're 'listening' or be specified in a conf file.

(The implementation above depends on python libraries that are only going to compile on OS X)